# phpMyAdmin 4.5.5.1 - Error in processing request Error code: 200 Error text: OK

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I use phpMyAdmin 4.5.5.1, the details displayed in the phpMyAdmin is given below for reference

```
Server: localhost via TCP/IP
Server type: MariaDB
Server version: 10.0.17-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution
Protocol version: 10
User: ashok@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)    

Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.14
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: 3c689b6abc90d36af9ac34fdc8b7b1b787fe5755 $
PHP extension: mysqli Documentation
PHP version: 5.6.14
```

I have 5 tables in a database. Among them, when I click "**Browse**" button in one table, it is taking forever and often not loading at all. Sometimes it shows a warning message as given below

```
Error in processing request
Error code: 200
Error text: OK
```

I searched in google for the error code 200, most of them suggests to update phpMyAdmin or change the text in config.inc.php file. But, in my case... all the database and table are displaying correctly except that table. Also, in PHP script it works fine.

My only guess is -- that table consists some Tamil/english letters in the records. May be the reason??

But, in older version phpMyAdmin it works fine. It don't know the exact version of the phpMyAdmin lastly it works fine. Because, I regularly update phpMyAdmin. Also, I rarely view tables using phpMyAdmin.

Kindly give suggestions..

Comment: Do you experience slowness when loading other tables or just that one? Can you export the table structure and try it at the demo server (https://demo.phpmyadmin.net)? If you copy that table to another database on your system does that table also give problems? Normally, Tamil characters should not cause any problem in this regard. Are there any interesting entries in the webserver error log?

Comment: @IsaacBennetch All tables are loading fastly except that table. I exported same database to my online server using cPanel, it works fine.

Comment: Unfortunately it sounds like some odd slowdown related to your server; if that structure works fine elsewhere then it makes me think your MySQL has some issue with that. I wonder if the MySQL slow query log has some hints. Failing that -- and it's not entirely pleasant -- perhaps the next thing to try would be copying that table (or entire database) on that server, dropping it, and renaming the copy. if you do that, *make sure you have a good backup first*, although copying is usually safe you don't want to mess around when it comes to live data.